# How to backup a dev & QA folder website structure?

Tags: backups

A site I just became in charge of uses a really simple two folder structure to host the dev site and the QA site. The sites are hosted on the company servers so I just have the sites' folders mapped on my desktop.

I would like to run some kind of backup scheme, but I am finding it hard to think of a way to do this effectively.

The problem is that we aren't using any revision control software, and since the servers aren't controlled by me, I don't think I will be able to implement anything like that. Or could I?

The entire site is static too, so no DB's or anything besides html, images, PDFs, etc.

Comment: What would you like to backup? If you are using some revision control software (SVN, git, etc..), you could back up only that and the DB dumps (and maybe some external library/file that doesnt need versioning).

Comment: The problem is that we aren't using any revision control software, and since the servers aren't controlled by me, I don't think I will be able to implement anything like that. Or could I?

Comment: The entire site is static too, so no DB's or anything besides html, images, PDFs, etc.

Comment: Do you have root access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement revision control if I were in you. You might have to change a couple of things since it's all html, maybe making some dynamic code for paths or similar problems that might occur. The production server should not have the revision software's directories in its tree, so it could be done even if you do not control the servers (although it might be more problematic/slow to deploy code). If you could access the servers, I would keep dev and QA folders under version control, then a deployment script from QA to production. In case you couldnt, you could just run deployment scripts from your local machines to your live server (so deploy local.dev to live.dev, local.qa to live.qa, and probably live.QA to production). Doing so you would need to backup only the version control folder (that can be on any server you'd like).

If it's sounds too overkill and you can run unix utils on your server, you might have a look at rsync to backup incrementally (this utility would also help deployment speed)

Comment: Yeah I like both ideas, but it seems crazy complicated to implement. I have never used SVN, git, or any other revision control.

Comment: It's not very complicated, but depending on your set-up could get slightly more complicated. To have a basic version it's probably 4-5 commands - and there's plenty of documentation on the net (at least for git and SVN). And if things go wrong we are always here :)

Comment: True, I will look into it and see if its possible. The only thing is that I don't even have access to the live folder. Once I drop something into QA it gets taken through a security check and then posted live. Would that be a problem?

Comment: No problems. It would depend on the scripts that does the checks and all, but hopefully it will be alright (I guess you need just to make sure in QA you have only files relevant to the project, and not to the revision control software - but it's just a guess as I don't know how your system is set-up).

Answer (score 1):

Are they running Linux servers? You can do rsync remotely over SSH to your computer and setup a cron job to backup all the files on a schedule